# Why does a space affect the identity comparison of equal strings?

Tags: python

I've noticed that adding a space to identical strings makes them compare unequal using `is`, while the non-space versions compare equal.

```
a = 'abc'
b = 'abc'
a is b
#outputs: True

a = 'abc abc'
b = 'abc abc'
a is b
#outputs: False
```

I have read [this question about comparing strings with `==` and `is`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1504717/2359271). I think this is a different question because the space character is changing the behavior, not the length of the string. See:

```
a = 'abc'
b = 'abc'
a is b # True

a = 'gfhfghssrtjyhgjdagtaerjkdhhgffdhfdah'
b = 'gfhfghssrtjyhgjdagtaerjkdhhgffdhfdah'
a is b # True
```

Why does adding a space to the string change the result of this comparison?

Comment: This question is worded differently, but the answers to the other question work here, as the key is recognizing what `is` does and how it differs from `==`.

Comment: There was a comment that got deleted referring you to the difference between "is" and "==". Is that your issue, or are you curious as to why the strings have the same identity if there is no space, but have different identities when there is a space character... Other non-printable characters also make the identities different.

Comment: I did ask NOTHING like == or the differance betweeen == and is, sry

Comment: A good article on the topic: http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The python interpreter caches some strings based on certain criteria, the first `abc` string is cached and used for both but the second is not. It is the same for small ints from `-5` to `256`.

Because the strings are interned/cached  assigning `a` and `b` to `"abc"` makes `a` and `b` point to the same objects in memory so using `is`, which checks if two objects are actually  the same object, returns `True`.

The second string `abc abc` is not cached so they are two entirely different object in memory so out identity check using `is` returns `False`. This time `a` is **not** `b`. They are both pointing to different objects in memory.

```
In [43]: a = "abc" # python caches abc
In [44]: b = "abc" # it reuses the object when assigning to b
In [45]: id(a)
Out[45]: 139806825858808    # same id's, same object in memory
In [46]: id(b)
Out[46]: 139806825858808    
In [47]: a = 'abc abc'   # not cached  
In [48]: id(a)
Out[48]: 139806688800984    
In [49]: b = 'abc abc'    
In [50]: id(b)         # different id's different objects
Out[50]: 139806688801208
```

The criteria for caching strings is if the string only has *letters*, *underscores* and *numbers* in the string so in your case the space does not meet the criteria.

Using the interpreter there is one case where you can end up pointing to the same object even when the string does not meet the above criteria, multiple assignments.

```
In [51]: a,b  = 'abc abc','abc abc'

In [52]: id(a)
Out[52]: 139806688801768

In [53]: id(b)
Out[53]: 139806688801768

In [54]: a is b
Out[54]: True
```

Looking  [codeobject.c source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/codeobject.c) for deciding the criteria we see `NAME_CHARS` decides what can be interned:

```
#define NAME_CHARS \
    "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

/* all_name_chars(s): true iff all chars in s are valid NAME_CHARS */

static int
all_name_chars(unsigned char *s)
{
    static char ok_name_char[256];
    static unsigned char *name_chars = (unsigned char *)NAME_CHARS;

    if (ok_name_char[*name_chars] == 0) {
        unsigned char *p;
        for (p = name_chars; *p; p++)
            ok_name_char[*p] = 1;
    }
    while (*s) {
        if (ok_name_char[*s++] == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

A string of length  0 or 1  will always be shared as we can see in the `PyString_FromStringAndSize` function  in the [stringobject.c](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Objects/stringobject.c) source.

```
/* share short strings */
    if (size == 0) {
        PyObject *t = (PyObject *)op;
        PyString_InternInPlace(&t);
        op = (PyStringObject *)t;
        nullstring = op;
        Py_INCREF(op);
    } else if (size == 1 && str != NULL) {
        PyObject *t = (PyObject *)op;
        PyString_InternInPlace(&t);
        op = (PyStringObject *)t;
        characters[*str & UCHAR_MAX] = op;
        Py_INCREF(op);
    }
    return (PyObject *) op;
}
```

Not directly related to the question but for those interested `PyCode_New` also from the `codeobject.c` source shows how more strings are interned when building a codeobject once the strings meet the criteria in `all_name_chars`.

```
PyCodeObject *
PyCode_New(int argcount, int nlocals, int stacksize, int flags,
       PyObject *code, PyObject *consts, PyObject *names,
       PyObject *varnames, PyObject *freevars, PyObject *cellvars,
       PyObject *filename, PyObject *name, int firstlineno,
       PyObject *lnotab)
{
    PyCodeObject *co;
    Py_ssize_t i;
    /* Check argument types */
    if (argcount < 0 || nlocals < 0 ||
        code == NULL ||
        consts == NULL || !PyTuple_Check(consts) ||
        names == NULL || !PyTuple_Check(names) ||
        varnames == NULL || !PyTuple_Check(varnames) ||
        freevars == NULL || !PyTuple_Check(freevars) ||
        cellvars == NULL || !PyTuple_Check(cellvars) ||
        name == NULL || !PyString_Check(name) ||
        filename == NULL || !PyString_Check(filename) ||
        lnotab == NULL || !PyString_Check(lnotab) ||
        !PyObject_CheckReadBuffer(code)) {
        PyErr_BadInternalCall();
        return NULL;
    }
    intern_strings(names);
    intern_strings(varnames);
    intern_strings(freevars);
    intern_strings(cellvars);
    /* Intern selected string constants */
    for (i = PyTuple_Size(consts); --i >= 0; ) {
        PyObject *v = PyTuple_GetItem(consts, i);
        if (!PyString_Check(v))
            continue;
        if (!all_name_chars((unsigned char *)PyString_AS_STRING(v)))
            continue;
        PyString_InternInPlace(&PyTuple_GET_ITEM(consts, i));
    }
```

*This answer is based on simple assignments using the cpython interpreter, as far as interning in relation to functions or any other functionality outside of simple assignments, that was not asked nor answered.*

If anyone with a greater  understanding of c code has anything to add feel free to edit.

There is a much more thorough explanation [here](http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/) of the whole string interning.

Comment: Your right about the numbers as a=260, b=260 ---> a is b is False... However what's the answer about my strings?

Comment: No since a='rgaerdavaerdgvrdversdvseDvaerdvreds', b=rgaerdavaerdgvrdversdvseDvaerdvreds is True.. its about the char SPACE and not about long or small

Comment: Note: the dup question **does** contain the information you are giving here, in the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1504848/510937).

Comment: So a string with SPACE doesn't get cached! Am I right?

Comment: @midkin It's *useless* to think about when that happens because there are *no guarantees*. We **cannot** say that if there's a space it doesn't get cached because it *may* happen now, and not in the next bugfix release. Different python implementations will use different ways of determining when to intern, and different versions of the same implementation are free to disagree in this regard.

Comment: @Bakuriu I keep your answer as right! It just seems that in python's 3.4.2 idle string with SPACE are not getting cached!

Comment: I decided to downvote your answer because you are providing *false information*. If you want to add a paragraph as your last one you should either 1) provide a reference to some documentation that mentions that or 2) Providing a link to the source code where that is done *and* clearly mention that this is bound to change with implementations and versions. As it stands your answer is suggesting that such a rule exist and can be relied upon, **which is false** (at least, as far as I know. If I'm wrong prove it with a reference).

Comment: @PadraicCunningham since I think your answer is "answering" most of what i needed to hear i ll choose it as my answer! 
Btw thanks all for your comments!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That's not a reference from the documentation or any official document about the python language. Also: note that right after mentioning interning it mentions peephole optimizations which is exactly one point where what you say fails: put `a = 'abc abc'` and `b = 'abc abc'` inside a function and suddenly `a is b` returns `True`.

Comment: @Bakuriu,  multiple assignments are not single assignments so there is a distinct difference, a function is not mentioned  anywhere, what is asked in the question and demonstrated in the answer is simple assignments, there is no mention of functions anywhere just an explanation for the question asked.

Comment: Multiple assignments are not the issue per se, the thing is that the REPL sees both strings _on the same line_, thus making a peephole optimization possible. For example `a='x y'; b='x y'` in REPL will cause `x y` to be folded and interned as well.

Comment: @georgm yes, what I was trying to say was in the purest form when you create a simple single assignment  one per line the string will be interned based on the criteria. The  peephole optimisation is another part where the are certain limits on length etc.. but that is another topic. If you know of anything related that is not covered feel free to edit

Comment: @martijnpieters , I referenced your article in codementor in a comment before i edited after looking at the source, in your article it states  that the string must start with an underscore or a letter but it seems that it can also start with a number, the only criteria is that it must be one of the three no?

Comment: Shouldn't the second comment in the first code block be 'it reuses the object when assigning to **b**'?

Comment: @BioGeek, yep, fixed.