# difference between tuple memory allocation and normal variable memory allocation

Tags: python, memory, memory-management

```
>>> a = 300
>>> b = 300
>>> id(a)
34709776
>>> id(b)
34709824
```

In above case a and b memory locations are not same

```
>>> (a, b) = 300, 300
>>> id(a)
34709632
>>> id(b)
34709632
```

But when assigning using tuple memory locations are same for both a&b. why?

Comment: Because -5 - 256 are the most used numbers. In `(a, b) = 300, 300` you are seeing peephole optimization where the object is reused using multiple assignment. `a, b = 300, 300` would do the same, Interning has a cost so doing it for every number would not be practical

Comment: thanks  @PadraicCunningham i got clarity on Memory allocation, but what about string objects caching?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329498/why-does-a-space-effect-the-identity-comparison-of-equal-strings/28329522#28329522

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I got for a `a, b = 300, 300`:

```
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               2 ((300, 300))
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

As for a normal `a = 300; b = 300` Python uses two separate `LOAD_CONST`'s, my guess would be that it is some sort of optimization for this kind of assignment.

Comment: In first and second line, what is 2, is it loading and unpacking two constants..?