# Why variables holding same value has the common ID in Python?

Tags: python

In Python:

```
>>> a = "Hello"
>>> b = "Hello"
>>> id(a) == id(b)
True
```

Why? Can this create a problem in a complex programs which refer to the memory locations of the object?

Comment: In Python you generally don't *"refer to the memory locations"* - strings are immutable, so the fact that *equal* strings (same characters in the same order) might also be *identical* (same exact object) doesn't really matter. The problem comes when you rely on `str_a is str_b` in production code when you really mean `str_a == str_b`, as although identical strings are necessarily equal the reverse is not guaranteed.

Comment: You are seeing string interning, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329498/why-does-a-space-effect-the-identity-comparison-of-equal-strings, your example will fail with `a = "$foo"` and `b = "$foo"`, cpython will intern any strings made up of any  letters,  underscores and digits so becasue `$` is used the string won't be iterned, it is definitely not something to rely on

Answer (score 6):

From [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types)

> For immutable types *[like strings]*, operations that compute new
>   values may actually return a reference to any existing object with the
>   same type and value. E.g., after `a = 1; b = 1`, `a` and `b` may or
>   may not refer to the same object with the value one, depending on the
>   implementation...

Comment: strings not made up of digits, letters or an underscore will not be interned unless you do `a, b = "$foo", "$foo"` or the strings are in a function. a = `"$foo`" and `b = "$foo"` in an interpreter will not return the same id. In cpython small ints are cached so they are always going to have the same id

Comment: You also need to address *Can this create a problem in a complex programs which refer to the memory locations of the object*