# Why does '() is ()' return True when '[] is []' and '{} is {}' return False?

Tags: python, tuples, identity, python-internals

From what I've been aware of, using `[]`, `{}` or `()` to instantiate objects returns a new instance of `list`, `dict` or `tuple` respectively; a new instance object with *a new identity*.

This was pretty clear to me until I actually tested it and I noticed that `() is ()` actually returns `True` instead of the expected `False`:

```
>>> () is (), [] is [], {} is {}
(True, False, False)
```

as expected, this behavior is also manifested when creating objects with [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list), [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) and [`tuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-tuple) respectively:

```
>>> tuple() is tuple(), list() is list(), dict() is dict()
(True, False, False)
```

The only relevant piece of information I could find in [the docs for `tuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) states:

> [...] For example, `tuple('abc')` returns `('a', 'b', 'c')` and `tuple([1, 2, 3])` returns `(1, 2, 3)`. **If no argument is given, the constructor creates a new empty tuple, `()`.**

Suffice to say, this isn't sufficient for answering my question.

So, why do empty tuples have the same identity whilst others like lists or dictionaries do not?

Comment: Related: [How is tuple implemented in CPython?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14135542)

Comment: Worth noting that it's not just empty tuples. `(1,) is (1,)` for example can also return `True`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

#### In short:

CPython internally creates a C list of tuple objects whose first element contains the empty tuple. Every time `tuple()` or `()` is used, Python will return the existing object contained in the aforementioned C list and not create a new one.

Such mechanism does not exist for `dict` or `list` objects which are, on the contrary, *recreated from scratch every time*.

This is most likely related to the fact that immutable objects (like tuples) cannot be altered and, as such, are guaranteed to not change during execution. This is further solidified when considering that `frozenset() is frozenset()` returns `True`; like `()` an empty `frozenset` [is considered an singleton in the implementation of CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L1082). With mutable objects, *such guarantees are not in place* and, as such, there's no incentive to cache their zero element instances (i.e their contents could change with the identity remaining the same).

**Take note:** *This isn't something one should depend on, i.e one shouldn't consider empty tuples to be singletons. No such guarantees are explicitly made in the documentation so one should assume it is implementation dependent.*

---

#### How it is done:

In the most common case, the implementation of CPython is compiled with two macros [`PyTuple_MAXFREELIST`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/tupleobject.c#L11) and [`PyTuple_MAXSAVESIZE`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/tupleobject.c#L8) set to positive integers. The positive value for these macros results in the creation of an [array of `tuple` objects](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/tupleobject.c#L19) with size `PyTuple_MAXSAVESIZE`.

When `PyTuple_New` is called with the parameter `size == 0` it makes sure to [add a new empty tuple](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/tupleobject.c#L120) to the list if it doesn't already exist:

```C
if (size == 0) {
    free_list[0] = op;
    ++numfree[0];
    Py_INCREF(op);          /* extra INCREF so that this is never freed */
}
```

Then, if a new empty tuple is requested, the one that is located in the [first position of this list](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/tupleobject.c#L84) is going to get returned instead of a new instance:

```C
if (size == 0 && free_list[0]) {
    op = free_list[0];
    Py_INCREF(op);
    /* rest snipped for brevity.. */
```

One additional reason causing an incentive to do this is the fact that function calls construct a tuple to hold the positional arguments that are going to be used. This can be seen in the [`load_args`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c) function in `ceval.c`:

```C
static PyObject *
load_args(PyObject ***pp_stack, int na)
{
    PyObject *args = PyTuple_New(na);
    /* rest snipped for brevity.. */
```

which is called via [`do_call`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L1082) in the same file. If the number of arguments `na` is zero, an empty tuple is going to be returned.

In essence, this might be an operation that's performed frequently so it makes sense to not reconstruct an empty tuple every single time.

---

#### Further reading:

A couple more answers shed light on CPython's caching behaviour with immutables:

- For integers, another answer that digs in the source can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34964030/4952130).
- For strings, a handful of answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756699/is-operator-behaves-differently-when-comparing-strings-with-spaces), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329498/why-does-a-space-effect-the-identity-comparison-of-equal-strings) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245324/about-the-changing-id-of-a-python-immutable-string).

Comment: Would it be correct to say that this behavior does NOT adhere to the documented standard? And therefore is a bug?

Comment: @vijrox definitely not considered a bug; my advice is don't depend on this since there is no reference on them being singletons in the [Python Reference Manual](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html#reference-index). Notable singletons like `None`, `Ellipsis` and others are explicitly mentioned, `()` or `frozenset()` are not therefore it is safe to assume they are considered an implementation detail which one should not rely on.

Comment: Right -- however I was referring to the part of the documentation you pointed out in the question which says "If no argument is given, the constructor creates a new empty tuple, ()." This behavior seems (to me) to exactly contradict that part of the documentation.

Comment: @vijrox ah yes, that did make me scratch my head too. Maybe it is a case of not trying to make the reference manual too confusing; maybe it is written that way as to not enforce other implementations to have that restriction. I can't really know but, I get the confusion.

Comment: @vijrox no, it's just implementation detail. Empty tuples behave 100% accurate to language specification. Language specification does not say, that empty tuple cannot be a singleton. Same as language specification _does not say_ that small integers have to be cached (and yet, [in CPython they are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)). It's not guaranteed that `() is ()` is True, same as is not guaranteed that `3 is 3` is True, but if it does, it does not break any kind of contract between tuple class and they users.

Comment: The main pint is that, since tuples are immutable, from the point of view of Python code, a new empty tuple is not, for practical proposes, distinguishable from a recycled empty tuple. 
The behavior could make one could write buggy code if trying to use an empty tuple as a sentinel object, for example, to provide a default behavior, and therefore mistake a "not meant as sentinel" empty tuple as that one. Just use proper sentinels.

Comment: The pypy implementation for example is different. `() is ()` still returns True, but `() is tuple()` or `tuple() is tuple()` return False. And in jython all three forms return False.

Comment: @mata quite interesting, especially the `PyPy` case. This just goes to show that different implementations implement things according to their needs. Nice comment.

Comment: *"With mutable objects, such guarantees are not in place"* - Actually, the opposite guarantee is in place, though I'm not sure where that's documented. E.g. if I do `a = []; b = []`, then `a is b` is guaranteed to be false. Mutable objects need to be independent because they're mutable; changes to one can't be allowed to change a different one.