# Is the empty tuple in Python a "constant"

Tags: python, memory, tuples, python-internals

I want to make my code more (memory-)efficient. Right now we have a lot of functions that take an iterable as parameter like:

```
def foo(para,meter,iterable):
    #...
    pass
```

and sometimes we have to provide it an empty list to do its work properly: `foo(14,25,[])`. The problem is that each time a new list is constructed: it requires to allocate on the heap, and a list seems to 64 bytes of memory (on my own machine, tested with `sys.getsizeof([])`) whereas the empty tuple only 
takes a (potentially one time) 48 bytes.

I was therefore wondering whether the empty tuple is a constant. Since tuples are immutable, one can easily make the tuple with length `0` (so `()`) a constant in the program. This would decrease the "construction time" (well there is none since it only would set a reference to the constant) and reduce the amount of memory allocated.

My question is whether there are guarantees regarding the Python interpreter (that is any popular interpreter) that the empty tuple is indeed a constant such that `()` does not require construction time nor allocates additional memory.

Testing it with `id(..)` seems to support the theory that there is indeed only one zero-tuple:

```
>>> id(())
140290183798856
>>> a = ()
>>> id(a)
140290183798856
```

but it could be possible that at runtime the Python interpreter forks the tuple for some reason.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38328857/2301450

Comment: @vaultah: the question was not why. I think the question makes clear that I have an idea how it works behind the curtains. The question is whether it **always** holds that `() is ()`.

Comment: I think Jim's answer covers that too?

Comment: @vaultah: yes but the last time I went to a doctor my eyes were ok and I see *duplicate **question***, not *duplicate **answer*** :) Unfortunately Belgian education only provides the opportunity to study five languages in secondary school, so I cannot exclude the possibility that the interpretation is simply wrong.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: if the answers to another question answer this one too, then the duplicate is fine. Jim's answer certainly echoes mine.

Answer (score 15):

In CPython, the empty tuple is a singleton. Only one copy is created, ever, then reused whenever you use `()` or use `tuple()` on an empty generator.

The [`PyTuple_new()` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Objects/tupleobject.c#l75) essentially does this:

```c
if (size == 0 && free_list[0]) {
    op = free_list[0];
    Py_INCREF(op);
    // ...
    return (PyObject *) op;
}
```

So if the tuple size is 0 (empty) and `free_list[0]` object exists (the existing empty tuple singleton), just use that.

See [How is tuple implemented in CPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135542/how-is-tuple-implemented-in-cpython/14135865#14135865) for more details on `free_list`; CPython will also re-use already-created `tuple` instances up to length 20.

This is an *implementation detail*. Other implementations (Jython, IronPython, PyPy) do not have to do the same.