# Sort list of strings by two substrings using lambda function

Tags: python, string, sorting, lambda

So I have a list of strings that looks roughly like this:

```
list = ['file.t00Z.wrff02.grib2', 'file.t00Z.wrff03.grib2', 'file.t00Z.wrff00.grib2',
        'file.t00Z.wrff05.grib2', 'file.t00Z.wrff04.grib2', 'file.t00Z.wrff01.grib2', 
        'file.t06Z.wrff01.grib2', 'file.t06Z.wrff00.grib2', 'file.t06Z.wrff02.grib2', ...]
```

I recently asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46165231/sort-list-of-strings-by-digits-appearing-in-each-element) wherein I learned how to sort my list of strings by substring using a lambda function:

`list.sort(key=lambda x: x[x.find('wrff'):])`

But now I need to know if there's a way to sort by two different substrings, almost like a composite primary key in a database. I'd like to sort the files first by the two digits following "file.t", and then by the two digits following "wrff". Is there a way that both of these actions can be performed at once?

**SOLUTION**: I wound up using the two-tuple lambda function sort that user Moses Koledoye recommended below, but I ran into problems when trying to apply this sorting process to groups of filenames with different naming conventions.

In my script I have 3 Python objects which grab files from unique data directories and form a list (like the one above) containing the files. Each of the objects grab files with different naming conventions, and each different group of files has a varying number of digit groups within their names.

To handle this without adding complexity, I decided to use the **natsort** module that user Jared Gougen suggested, and it worked very nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` to pick those first two digits and then use them for sorting in a 2-tuple:

```
import re

lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: tuple(int(i) for i in re.findall('\d+', x)[:2]))
print(lst)
# ['file.t00Z.wrff00.grib2', 'file.t00Z.wrff01.grib2', 'file.t00Z.wrff02.grib2', 
#  'file.t00Z.wrff03.grib2', 'file.t00Z.wrff04.grib2', 'file.t00Z.wrff05.grib2', 
#  'file.t06Z.wrff00.grib2', 'file.t06Z.wrff01.grib2', 'file.t06Z.wrff02.grib2', ...]
```

This takes the first digit after `file.t` and then that after `wrff`.

Comment: @ChristianDean The answer addresses that. See `[:2]`.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Nice answer. +1 Sorry about that. Like I said, my brain was fried.

Comment: @ChristianDean does have a point though, this will capture stray 1-digit sequences and sequences not after the requested substrings (which may or may not be an issue).

Answer (score 4):

It seems like this is approaching the area where regular expressions are useful. Here's one solution which captures the two subsequences of digits that you require.

```
import re

get_indices = lambda s: re.match('^.*?file\.t([0-9]{2}).*?wrff([0-9]{2}).*$', s).groups()
sorted(file_names, key=get_indices)
```

Or, in situations like these, I'm often trying to [*naturally sort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order) file names. In those cases, I have the following set of functions in a library file.

```
import re

def tryint(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except:
        return s

def getchunks(string):
    return [tryint(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', string)]

def sort_naturally(l):
    return sorted(l, key=getchunks)
```

The library [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) was written to naturally sort on a more comprehensive level if you're looking for something more heavy duty.

Comment: Wow the natsort package is a really neat suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: The re.split feature is really handy. Using the tryint(s) defined here, and sorting a `glob.glob("/usr/share/icons/"+theme+"/*/"+category+"/"+name+".*")` I have my key function `return [tryint(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)',x.split("/")[5])]` which works.