# How to sort a list using digits in each item of the list? Python

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

`['God: 250', 'Noob: 0', 'Bot: 20']`

I would like to sort the list in ascending order using the numbers at the end of each element. The end product should look something like this:

`['Noob: 0', 'Bot: 20', 'God: 250']`

I have had a look at other solutions in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46165231/sort-list-of-strings-by-digits-appearing-in-each-element) but have had no luck. Any help is appreciated.

**SOLUTION**

`list.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split(":")[1].strip()))`

Comment: `a.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split(":")[1].strip()))`

Comment: That works, thank you. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(sorted(myList, key=lambda x: int("".join([i for i in x if i.isdigit()]))))
```