# Python slice shows same id location

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, slice

I'm total beginner to Python, so please could you explain me why the following situation happens. 
Consider the following code:

```
>>> A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> B = A[0:2]
>>> print id(A) == id(B)
False
>>> print id(A[0]) == id(B[0])
True                              #Why?
>>> A[0] = 9
>>> A
[9, 2, 3, 4]
>>> B 
[1, 2]
>>> print id(A[0]) == id(B[0])
False                             #Contradiction?
```

As you can see from the code above, I slice the list A and copy it to B, but, why `print id(A[0]) == id(B[0])` evalutes `True`on the first one but the opposite when I change either of A or B's value?

Comment: [CPython caches small integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers) so any value from -5 to 256 will have same id anytime you check it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329498/why-does-a-space-affect-the-identity-comparison-of-equal-strings/28329522#28329522

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `B = A[0:2]`, that ends up essentially doing this, as part of it: `B[0] = A[0]`. So the object (the integer `1`) in `A[0]` is the same object which is in `B[0]`.

When you set `A[0] = 9`, then those objects are no long the same.

Also, as @ŁukaszRogalski pointed out CPython caches small integers. So we've got `A[0] == 1 == B[0]`, and `id(1) == id(1)`.

When `A[0] == 9`, then `9 != 1 == B[0]`, and `id(9) != id(1)`.

Comment: oh so it has nothing to do with the memory location?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id If it's CPython, it would be the memory location. But if it's not, it's just guaranteed to be unique for a unique object.

Comment: Also, my answer is slightly off. Hang on while I adjust it.

Comment: @Burak. I would take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15667189/3220135) question and the answers to it.. they describe it pretty well

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
id(1) == id(1) #True
```

The reason is that these number constants will be reused throughout the program. So its like some memory is given to store 1 and then wherever 1 is mentioned in the program, the same memory will be used so only a reference to that memory will be created. Object remains the same.

Comment: Oh, ok I initially thought it always fetches memory location rather than the actual value. :)

Comment: Be assured that in your case, A and B are referring to different things.

Comment: @Burak it does, but python will only store one object for each literal integer.

Comment: The problem comes when your list contains references instead of constants. In that case the changes made from 1 place will reflect automatically to another place. We do deep copy in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, python doesn't create new objects from every item within a list, whenever you copy/slice a it.

But, Although this won't cause any trouble with immutable objects, you should be careful with mutable objects:

```
In [22]: A = [[1, 2], 2, 3, 4]

In [23]: B = A[0:2]

In [24]: id(A[0]) == id(B[0])
Out[24]: True

In [27]: A[0][1] = 99

In [28]: B
Out[28]: [[1, 99], 2]
```

In this case you can use `copy.deepcopy` to create a new object of the slice:

```
In [32]: import copy

In [33]: B = copy.deepcopy(A[0:2])

In [34]: A[0][1] = 5

In [35]: B
Out[35]: [[1, 99], 2]

In [36]: id(A[0]) == id(B[0])
Out[36]: False
           ^
        New Object
```